# Classification accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, classification, matlab

I am classifying text based on news headlines and I am achieving accuracy up to approx 80%. I want to improve it more.

But issue is that when I calculate the same with synonyms using the code below:

```
Doc = actxserver('Word.Application')    
X = cellfun(@(word) invoke( Doc,'SynonymInfo',word), words, 'UniformOutput', false);
Synonyms = cellfun(@(X) get(X,'MeaningList'), X, 'UniformOutput', false);
Synonyms = cellfun(@(X) [words{X}; Synonyms{X}], num2cell(1:numel(words)), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

My accuracy falls very badly below and reach 40% or less.

Why is this happening?

Comment: If you're trying to classify according to topic (you don't actually provide this information) my guess would be that word choice is indicative of topic. For example articles with a political slant may use the word "crisis" where articles about entertainment would use the word "disaster." Just a guess, it is hard to say since you haven't provided a lot of details.

Comment: @alto thanks for reply.. see.. I am classifying news on basis of their headlines and what I am doing iss that I pass words as well as their synonyms to classifier and perform pre-processing and all tasks my accuracy becomes 40% but when I only pass words I get 80%. I a not getting the reason for that...

Comment: "Classifying news" doesn't provide any more detail than what you had in the original question. What are you trying to predict? Topic (politics vs sports vs entertainment vs ...), time (is this article old?), news vs non-news, etc. Again, my guess is that word choice is more informative in your application than meaning. It could also be that you're adding synonyms that aren't actually synonyms in the context. A more principled approach you might try is [stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming).

Comment: @Rana This question is woefully under detailed. If the question is about Matlab code, it should be closed as being off topic.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that with synonyms you are catching more false negatives, which is decreasing true negatives, so that your [accuracy measure](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~dbd/cs831/notes/confusion_matrix/confusion_matrix.html) goes down.

Comment: So please guide how may I proceed? what change in code is to be done Mmm